# SQL Server 2012 need to increment sequence number when bit column changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, lag

I have a table like this:

```
dDate            amount sigma  
-----------------------------
2015-01-01         0,00     1  
2015-11-01       150,00     0  
2015-11-10        25,00     0  
2015-11-11      1028,90     0  
2015-11-12       878,90     1  
2015-11-15       150,00     0  
2015-12-13       723,90     1
```

I need to have an increment of a sequence number every time the `sigma` column changes, so this should be the result:

```
dDate            Amount sigma  seqNr
------------------------------------
2015-01-01         0,00     1      0
2015-11-01       150,00     0      1
2015-11-10        25,00     0      1
2015-11-11      1028,90     0      1
2015-11-12       878,90     1      2
2015-11-15       150,00     0      3
2015-12-13       723,90     1      4
```

Should I use the `lag` function for this?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be last two rows  3 and 4?

Comment: Shouldn't the first row be "1" rather than "0"?  Or, perhaps the sequence should be "0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4"?

Comment: What is the primary key of the table?  Also, what is the datatype of sigma?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want to count the number of "1"s up to any given value.  (This assumes the first value should really be "1" in your example.) In SQL Server 2012+, you can do this using a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when sigma = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by ddate)
from t;
```

Actually, if `sigma` only takes on 0 and 1, you can simplify this to:

```
select t.*,
       sum(cast(sigma as int)) over (order by ddate)
from t;
```

If you want the actual changes (either 1 --> 0 or 0 --> 1), then lag and cumulative sum are helpful:

```
select t.*,
       sum(inc) over (order by ddate) 
from (select t.*,
             (case when sigma <> lag(sigma) over (order by ddate) then 1
                   else 0 end) as inc
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Just read up on lag - that is an amazingly useful function I wish I had known about before now

Answer (score 0):

this is different variable names but same thing
same as Gordon but abs rather than case - thought I might be able to do it in one pass

```
  select *, sum(inc) over (order by [ID]) as seq 
  from 
  (   SELECT [ID], [OnOff]
           , isnull(abs(cast(OnOff as int) - lag(cast(OnOff as int)) over (order by [ID])),0) as inc
      FROM [test].[dbo].[Table_2]
  ) tt
```